# Repeated objects with input values

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, mongoose

I have a javascript repeater that creates forms,
but the problem is that when I bring the values ​​they are all entered in a single object instead of separate objects, which inside array locations should create a similar structure.

```
"locations":[
        {
           "coordinates":[
              -80.128473,
              25.781842
           ],
           "description":"Lummus Park Beach",
           "day":1
        },
        {
           "coordinates":[
              -80.647885,
              24.909047
           ],
           "description":"Islamorada",
           "day":2
        },
   ]
```

My code takes information from inputs but puts it in the same object instead of separate objects.

```js
//This is the code which take input value and inser in boject structure

const createTour_form = document.querySelector('.form-create__tour');
if (createTour_form) {
    createTour_form.addEventListener('submit', (cr) => {
        cr.preventDefault();
        
        //Ceeate an empty array
         
          let loc_coordinates = [];
            let loc_description = [];
            let loc_day = [];
            let get_locations = [];

            //Get Coordinates
            document.querySelectorAll(".location_field_card").forEach(f => {
              let obj = [];
              f.querySelectorAll(".location_new_tour").forEach(ele => obj[ele.value] = ele.value || "");
              loc_coordinates.push(Object.keys(obj));
            });

             //Get Descriptions
             document.querySelectorAll(".location_field_card").forEach(f => {
              let obj1 = {};
               f.querySelectorAll(".description_location").forEach(ele => obj1[ele.name] = ele.value || "");
              loc_description.push(obj1)
            });

             //Get Day
            document.querySelectorAll(".location_field_card").forEach(f => {
              let obj2 = {};
               f.querySelectorAll(".location_day").forEach(ele => obj2[ele.name] = ele.value || "");
              loc_day.push(obj2)
            });
           
            //Reverse Coordinates
            const getGeo = [...loc_coordinates].toString().split(',').reverse().join(' ').replace(' ', ' ,');
            get_locations.push(getGeo)


            const getLocation = Object.values(...loc_description);
            const getValLocation = getLocation.toString();
            const getDay = Object.values(...loc_day);
            const getValDay =parseInt(getDay.toString());


           
            let getTotaLocation = new Object({
                "coordinates":[...get_locations],
                "description":getValLocation,
                "day":getValDay
            });
          

      
            console.log(getTotaLocation);

         
         
    })
  }
```

```html
<form class="form form-create__tour">
   <h1 class="title--create--tourpage">Locations</h1>
               <div class="form__group all_tours_options">
                  <div id="add_location_field">
                     <div class="location_field_card">
                        <p class="subfield_natours_create_tour">Location</p>
                        <input class="form__input location_new_tour"  type="text"  value="24.5647846,-81.8068843">
                        <p class="subfield_natours_create_tour">Location Description</p>
                        <input class="form__input description_location"  type="text" value="Lummus Park Beach">
                        <p class="subfield_natours_create_tour">Day</p>
                        <input class="form__input location_day"  type="number" value="1" >
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn--small--add btn--green" id="add_location_fields">Add Location       Field</button>
               </div>
               
               <div class="form__group right"><button class="btn btn--small btn--green" id="createTour">Create Tour</button></div>
            </form>
            
    
    <!--This Javascript code generate new fields when Add Locaton field is clicked-->
    <script>
      const addLocation = document.getElementById('add_location_fields');
         if(addLocation){
            let count_createdCards = 0;
            let count_Deletebutton = 0;
            let incrementFunction = 0;
            addLocation.addEventListener('click',(st)=>{
               st.preventDefault();
               let createAddField = document.getElementById('add_location_field');
         // Crd
        
         count_createdCards++;
         count_Deletebutton ++;
         incrementFunction ++;
         let card = document.createElement('div');
            card.setAttribute('class','location_field_card');
            card.setAttribute('id','delete_card_'+ count_createdCards)
           
         //First Card Title 
         let cartTitle1 = document.createElement('p');  
             cartTitle1.setAttribute('class','subfield_natours_create_tour');
             cartTitle1.textContent = 'Location'; 
         let inputLocation = document.createElement('input'); 
             inputLocation.classList.add('form__input');
             inputLocation.classList.add('location_new_tour');
             inputLocation.setAttribute('type','text');
             inputLocation.setAttribute('value','24.5647846,-81.8068843');
          //Second Card Title
         let cartTitle2 = document.createElement('p');  
             cartTitle2.setAttribute('class','subfield_natours_create_tour');
             cartTitle2.textContent = 'Location Description'; 
         let inputDescription_location = document.createElement('input');
             inputDescription_location.classList.add('form__input'); 
             inputDescription_location.classList.add('description_location'); 
             inputDescription_location.setAttribute('type','text');
             inputDescription_location.setAttribute('value','Lummus Park Beach');
         //Third Card Title
         let cartTitle3 = document.createElement('p');  
             cartTitle3.setAttribute('class','subfield_natours_create_tour');
             cartTitle3.textContent = 'Day'; 
         let inputDescription_day = document.createElement('input'); 
             inputDescription_day.classList.add('form__input'); 
             inputDescription_day.classList.add('location_day');
             inputDescription_day.setAttribute('type','number');
             inputDescription_day.setAttribute('value','1');
         let removeButton = document.createElement('a');
             removeButton.classList.add('btn');
             removeButton.classList.add('btn--small--add'); 
             removeButton.classList.add('btn--red');
             removeButton.setAttribute('onclick','removeAction_'+count_Deletebutton+'()');
         let removeScript = document.createElement('script');
         removeScript.innerHTML = "function removeAction_".concat(count_Deletebutton, "() {\n\n var delCard_")
                                          .concat(incrementFunction, " = document.getElementById(\"delete_card_")
                                          .concat(count_createdCards, "\");\ndelCard_")
                                          .concat(incrementFunction, ".remove();}");
             removeButton.textContent = 'Remove Location Field';   
             card.appendChild(cartTitle1);
             card.appendChild(inputLocation);
             card.appendChild(cartTitle2);
             card.appendChild(inputDescription_location);
             card.appendChild(cartTitle3);
             card.appendChild(inputDescription_day);
             card.appendChild(removeButton);
             card.appendChild(removeScript);
             createAddField.appendChild(card);
             

            });
         }
    
    
    </script>
```

Comment: You would be best advised to make an MRE that isolates your logic from the DOM.

Comment: I had a crack at it, but it's complex. 

Here is what you need to do: rather than Array.forEach and Array.push, you want Array.map. 

Take a look at this article: https://joshwulf.com/blog/2020/03/why-array-map/

You also would do well to extract your data transformation logic from the DOM. 

Write code to grab the data from the DOM, then pass it to an assembler. You can test the assembler with unit tests then.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding in the folds that repeat the dynamic id:

```
  //Increment Coordinates
   let incrementCoordiantes = 0; 
   //Increment Description
   let incrementDescription = 0; 
   //Increment Day
   let incrementDay = 0;

 addLocation.addEventListener('click',(st)=>{
           let createAddField = document.getElementById('add_location_field');
    
     incrementCoordiantes ++;
     incrementDescription ++;
     incrementDay ++;
     let card = document.createElement('div');
       ......
       inputLocation.setAttribute('id','getCoordinates_'+ incrementCoordiantes);
       inputDescription_location.setAttribute('id','getDescription_' + incrementDescription);
       inputDescription_day.setAttribute('id','getDay_' + incrementDay );
```

I use `querySelectorAll` to get the number of colums from repeater and after that I use `for` to incremet id to match the id from html file, all the value it's push after that in an array, and it's work.

```
   const push_location_data = [];
      const getAll_locations =  document.querySelectorAll(".location_field_card");
      for (let i=1; i< getAll_locations.length; i++) {

    let cord_lat_lng = 'getCoordinates_' + i;
    let cord_description = 'getDescription_' + i;
    let cord_day = 'getDay_' + i;

    let dinamic_obj = {
        coordinates:[[document.getElementById(cord_lat_lng).value].toString().split(',').reverse().join(' ').replace(' ', ' ,')],
        description:document.getElementById(cord_description).value,
        day:document.getElementById(cord_day).value
    }
  

    push_location_data.push(dinamic_obj);
};
```

[location arrray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7kAF.png)